# Zipping files and HTML5 File API

Tags: html, zip, fileapi

Is it possible to bundle files into a zip file using the File API, or another part of the HTML5 suite?  If so, are there any example implementations available?  If not, is this something likely to be supported by modern browsers in the next year or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know of anything built into HTML5 currently, I've seen some projects that are starting to touch on this in JavaScript.  You may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip) project, which allows you to *read* the contents of a zip file, and if it's compressed using the Deflate algorithm, can unzip them.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you might have been looking for. It's probably too late to help you, but I'll just leave this here for anyone else who might be interested.

http://stuartk.com/jszip/

Answer (score 1):

Another option which works really well with plain javascript is a zip API called [sendzip](http://www.sendzip.net). It allows you to create zip file on the fly and streaming it to users.